# How can I safely execute powershell script from C# with user entered string parameters?

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to use `System.Management.Automation`, to run a simple powershell command, with a parameter specified by the user (a `string` of text representing a comment).  It seems like this could be a security issue as there could be a way to inject code into this input.

So is there any way I can make this secure, and ONLY allow them to specify `string` inputs?

Comment: can you use process start with arguments?

Comment: One tip is to ensure that only a-Z and space are allowed. If anything else is present, strip it. Assuming this is for consumption in the US, at least. If you need more characters, then...

Answer (score 3):

The functions [AddArgument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.addargument.aspx) and [AddParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameter.aspx) directly change the parameter value. This means that if anyone tried to inject another command in the same string it won't work, the parameter just gets set to that string. Kind of the same thing as Parameterized Queries.